# Makefile can't find file when using vpath

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I use make, it says

```
gcc -I./header -c -g main.c
gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory
```

My makefile is here:

```
vpath %.c ./src
vpath %.h ./header

CC = gcc
FLAG = -I./header -c -g
objects = main.o a.o b.o

app: ${objects}
    ${CC} -o app ${objects}

main.o: main.c command.h
    ${CC} ${FLAG} main.c

a.o: a.c command.h
    ${CC} ${FLAG} a.c

b.o: b.c command.h
    ${CC} ${FLAG} b.c

clean: 
    -rm *.o app

.PHONY: clean
```

and files are stored like this:

```
.
|-- header
|   `-- command.h
|-- Makefile
`-- src
    |-- a.c
    |-- b.c
    `-- main.c
```

What's wrong with the Makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) instead of hard coded values for file names in recipes:

```
main.o: main.c command.h
    ${CC} ${FLAG} $<

...
```

This allows Make to insert the right file names found in `vpath`:

> When a prerequisite is found in another directory through directory search, this cannot change the recipe of the rule; they will execute as written. Therefore, you must write the recipe with care so that it will look for the prerequisite in the directory where make finds it.
>
> This is done with the automatic variables such as `$^` (see [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables)). For instance, the value of `$^` is a list of all the prerequisites of the rule, including the names of the directories in which they were found, and the value of `$@` is the target.